# Блокировка доступа к сайтам

Tags: debian

Привет всем!

Подскажите, через что ограничить доступ к сайтам на интернет шлюзе `Debian по ip/mac`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Юзай squid, там все это есть: группы, скорость, блокируемые сайты и тд.... если ты будешь через nat блочить это тупо, завтра тебе скажут заблочить доступ к сайту другому, после завтра третьему.... это бред) уже давно все придумано юзай squid

Comment: Сегодня появилось время решил попробовать и чет я туплю.Стоит Debian на нем Webmin и Sqiud и не могу разобраться как создать группу пользователей, а группе запретить все сайты кроме двух трех. Помогите кто знает.

Comment: читайте про сквид, ЧИТАЙТЕ. или вы хотите что бы вам все сделали? там все достаточно просто после прочтения документации

Answer (score 3):

Сайт, я так вас понял - это чьё-то *<доменное имя> [ip-адрес]*, доступ до которого из вашей локальной сети нужно ограничить.

Сайт доступен по протоколам 3,4 уровня модели OSI. Соответственно по MAC-адресу (2 уровень OSI) сделать ничего нельзя.

Для более корректного блокирования (по доменному имени) гуглите "proxy blacklist" или сразу "squid blacklist".

Для блокирования сайта по ip-адресу гуглите "iptables blacklist", но если изменится A-запись (т. е. ip-адрес сайта), то придётся это постоянно отслеживать и менять правила в iptables

Comment: Я не так объснил, есть локальная сеть, интернет которая получает через интернет шлюз на Debian'e.Так вот как закрыть например компу с ip x.x.x.10 доступ к сайту vk.com.

Comment: в гугле "squid blacklist". Можно добавить "acl http_access src ip". Там (в интернетах) очень много всего.. нужно почитать статьи по использованию сквида например на opennet.ru.

Answer (score 2):

Для блокировки по мак адресу

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j DROP
```

Для блокировки по IP

```
iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
```

Лучше сделать отдельными таблицами.

1. Создать две таблицы:

   ```
   iptables -N drop_maciptables -N drop_ip
   ```
2. Привязать таблицы к `INPUT` секции:

   ```
   iptables -I INPUT 1 -j drop_ipiptables -I INPUR 2 -j drop_mac
   ```
3. Добавить `IP` и `MAC` в таблицы:

   ```
   iptables -A drop_ip -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROPiptables -A drop_mac -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j DROP
   ```

Comment: ух.. ваще аж дух захватило!как    iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j DROPили     iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROPзаблокирует доступ к vk.com, например?

Comment: Вообще-то, FORWARD, а не INPUT

Answer (score 1):

squid в связке с dansguardian или sams. В интернете полно статей по их установке и настройке.

Answer (score 1):

Ну смотря как тебе нужно блокировать. Если от детей то не знаю, а если от вирусных сайтов то скачай антивирус аваст и он сам перенаправляет с вирусных сайтов на проверенные.